# Validate enum with associated values in a vec for uniqueness

Tags: rust

Below there is code in which I have defined a method with an input type of `Vec<Food>`. This method should validate if an arm, without checking the associated value, must be unique. It means it should contain at most 1 pizza, 1 cake and 1 subway. **Note**: it is not needed that all arms are in the `Vec`. I wrote some tests in the code below also, they still need to pass.

I have much more enum arms in my 'real' code, and my current way doesn't scale very well, so I was hoping there is a easier way.

```
fn main() {

}

enum Food {
    Cake(String),
    Pizza(i32),
    Subway(u64)
}

struct CustomError;

fn validate(foods: Vec<Food>) -> Result<(), CustomError> {
    let mut cake = false;
    let mut pizza = false;
    let mut subway = false;

    for f in foods.iter() {
        match f {
            Food::Cake(_) => {
                if cake {
                    return Err(CustomError)
                }

                cake = true;
            },
            Food::Pizza(_) => {
                if pizza {
                    return Err(CustomError)
                }

                pizza = true;
            },
            Food::Subway(_) => {
                if subway {
                    return Err(CustomError)
                }

                subway = true;
            },
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        assert!(validate(vec![Food::Pizza(1)]).is_ok());
        assert!(validate(vec![Food::Pizza(1), Food::Cake("Apple".to_owned())]).is_ok());
        assert!(validate(vec![]).is_ok());

        assert!(validate(vec![Food::Pizza(1), Food::Pizza(1)]).is_err());
        assert!(validate(vec![Food::Pizza(1), Food::Pizza(2)]).is_err());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare `enum` variants without caring about any associated data, the function [`std::mem::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html) is very useful. Given a value of an `enum` type, `std::mem::discriminant` returns a value of type [`std::mem::Discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/struct.Discriminant.html) which tells which variant the value is. `std::mem::Discriminant` implements `Hash`, so we can keep all the variants we've seen so far in a `HashSet` to check if there are any duplicates.

Just a small trick: `HashSet::insert` returns a boolean which is true when the inserted element isn't already in the set. That means we can combine the steps of checking if a discriminant has been seen and inserting a new discriminant.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::mem::discriminant;

enum Food {
    Cake(String),
    Pizza(i32),
    Subway(u64),
}

struct CustomError;

fn validate(foods: Vec<Food>) -> Result<(), CustomError> {
    let mut discriminants = HashSet::new();
    for food in foods {
        if !discriminants.insert(discriminant(&food)) {
            return Err(CustomError);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d0742d56a45cdbaffd98232bf4ad5e8)

Answer (score 0):

Rust doesn't have much by way of reflection capabilities, so I suspect the best you can do is write something like a [procedural macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) to generate a function containing the match statement which you described not wanting to write by hand.